# log4net permission issue to write to application event log when the user is not in admin group in Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, log4net, event-log

I am having log4net permission issue from ASP.Net 4.0 web application to write to application event log, when the user is not in administrator group in Windows 2008 R2 and IIS 7. We are using NT authentication and impersonation. Once I assign the user to admin group it works fine.
I tried with many permission settings like giving Authenticated Users full permission to Eventlog in registry etc. and none of them work. If any one can help that will be great.

When I had a similar issue with logging to eventlog from a .net 1.1 app on Windows 2003 server I did CustomSD entry as below link and it worked

http://mossipqueen.wordpress.com/2008/08/04/cannot-open-log-for-source-you-may-not-have-write-access/

The error I get is below from log4net internal log.

```
log4net:ERROR [EventLogAppender] Unable to write to event log [Application] using source [*******]
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source '*******'. You may not have write access. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID, UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[] rawData, String currentMachineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String source, String message, EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
   at log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here but it looks like a simple permissions issue for that user.  By default they don't have access to write to the application log file.  I know you played around with the permissions but I'm not sure exactly what permissions you assigned.

Here is a Microsoft article on doing exactly what you want to do to overcome the error you are seeing:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028427

If you follow this, you should solve your issue.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Checking this back again today. Thank you for the KB article. I tried the following with the last entry for authenticated users from command prompt run as administrator and it seem to work now wevtutil sl application /ca:O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;‌​‌​SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x3;;;AU)

Comment: I do get the below text at the top of the event log entry and if you know a way turn this off let me know                                              The description for Event ID 0 from source MyAppTest cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Comment: I created a utility program (Windows Form/C#)that will make the event source in the application event log and will remove the unnecessary message at the top and it seem to work (I was trying to create the event source and related entries directly in registry and it seems like in Windows 2008 it is not working due to some reason)